# Get a printers total page count from printserver

Tags: powershell, printing, wmi

I use a printserver for managing all printers. Now I am looking for a method to get the total page count of every printer connected to the printserver to learn something about each printers usage. First I thought about internal PowerShell commands but then I realized that there are no suitable cmdlets. Then I though about using WMI to query the printers. Here I am stuck with querying recent print jobs happening on the server. There I can see how many pages one of the recent print jobs have. But I have no idea how to get to know the total page count each printer has printed in its lifetime. How can I get to this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total prints (aka impressions or count) will be stored on the printer itself, if your printer has a web interface it will likely be available via this or by using SNMP.

How you query these might vary depending on the printers manufacturer, here's a good example of using SNMP:
https://serverfault.com/questions/329789/query-page-count-from-hp-web-jetadmin-10-2

Comment: So there is no general method for querying?

Comment: There's not a 'Get-PrinterTotalCount' type of command no, SNMP seems to work between models according to the linked question but I cannot confirm this.

Comment: I tested the method with SNMPTool and it finally worked! Thanks very much! Really appreciate your help!